# NUXT3 NuxtImg : Image rotate 90° when I use NuxtImg

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, nuxt.js

When I use NuxtImg, my images rotate at 90°. This problem appear with vertical mobile images, when I read it on supabase and display it. Before upload and on supabase, images are ok (portrait).

When I use img instead everthing is ok, images change and become portrait style...

My nuxt config :

```js
       image: {
  inject: true,
  quality: 80,
   format: ['webp'],
      screens: {
      'xs': 120,
      'sm': 240,
      'md': 290,
      'lg': 384,
      'xl': 480,
      'xxl': 480,
      '2xl': 480
    }, 

    domains: ['images.unsplash.com', 'draxies.com', 'qzlburhygrqslzasuiak.supabase.co']

},
```

My NuxtImg code :

```js
      <div class="relative pb-64 z-0">
        <NuxtImg class="absolute w-full h-full rounded-lg object-cover border-b shadow-md"
          :src="offer.offer_image_url" :alt="offer.offer_title" placeholder />
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Robert mentioned, this has to do with the EXIF metadata. The EXIF metadata tracks certain properties about images such as width, height, geolocation, orientation, etc.

The reason your image is displayed properly when you use a normal `<img>` tag and/or you view it on Supabase is because your **original** images are being served/used, and these contain the original orientation EXIF metadata; thus, your browser uses this EXIF metadata to orient the image correctly.

However, by default NuxtImage **removes/replaces** all of this original EXIF data when it pre-renders/optimizes them; thus, your browser no longer compensates by auto-rotating it properly, so you see the image in an incorrect orientation.

If you are using the [default image provider (which is IPX)](https://image.nuxt.com/get-started/providers#default-provider),
you can force NuxtImage to preserve the original EXIF orientation by specifying the following [provider metadata](https://image.nuxt.com/providers/ipx#additional-modifiers) on your `<NuxtImg>` and `<NuxtPicture>` elements:

```
<NuxtImg :modifiers="{ rotate: null }" />
<NuxtPicture :modifiers="{ rotate: null }" />
```

If the `rotate` modifier is present, but it does **not** contain a value, then NuxtImage will [fallback to the orientation that is specified in the EXIF metadata](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-operation#rotate) (FYI: if you're wondering why this links to Sharp, it's because IPX uses Sharp under the hood).

To be clear, this does **not** preserve the original EXIF metadata; instead, NuxtImage actually generates an image that matches the original EXIF orientation by rotating the pixels that are in the image.

### Additional Reading

- https://github.com/nuxt/image/issues/70
- https://github.com/unjs/ipx/issues/81
- https://github.com/unjs/ipx/#modifiers

Comment: @oemera that's great.  Can you give my answer an up vote then?

Comment: already did some that while ago, just commented now to hint others.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are rotating at 90 tiers when you operate NuxtImg so its not Nuxtimg issue its issue form server side. It could happen for EXIF data  store in image file. EXIF facts includes records approximately the image's orientation and some browser and photo viewers automatically apply that rotation.

So that issue you can tackle using following ways like

1.Add NuxtImg modifiers to using add custom rotate angle to you want that image

```js
<NuxtImg
  provider="imagekit"
  src="/default-image.jpg"
  :modifiers="{rotate: 90}"
/>
```

2. Add custom vue directives to modify the image rotation angle so create separate image_rotation.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.directive('image-rotation', {
  bind(el, binding) {
    const image = el;
    if (image.complete) {
      rotationImg(image);
    } else {
      image.addEventListener('load', () => {
        rotationImg(image);
      });
    }
  },
});
function rotationImg (image) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const dataContex = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  dataContex.save();
  dataContex.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  dataContex.rotate((image.getAttribute('data-orientation') || 0) * (Math.PI / 180));
  dataContex.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.height / 2, image.width, image.height);
  dataContex.restore();
  image.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
}
```

This image_rotation.js file include in nuxt.config.js file and this directives add in your above code like below

```js
<div class="relative pb-64 z-0">
    <NuxtImg class="absolute w-full h-full rounded-lg object-cover border-b shadow-md"
          :src="offer.offer_image_url" :alt="offer.offer_title" v-image-rotation  placeholder />
</div>
```

Might be this trick help for you..

Comment: Thanks very much. I already add a preview before upload. If image is rotated, people can change it. Thanks very much for this trick. I keep it ;-)